# What will be the product of this reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

I suspect the answer is either one of C or D, but how do I know which one?
Since such a stable carbocation is being formed, I can't choose whether the reaction will be an Sn1 or Sn2 (elimination semms unlikely).

[image]
But do I need to transform this fischer projection to some other form for me to easily answer this question?

Comment: Neighbouring group participation of the OMe leads to a double inversion, i.e. overall retention of configuration

Comment: I just looked up NGP on the Internet and learned something new. Thank you :).and btw using NGP as a method, I am getting the correct answer.